# finding execution flow in a huge java code base

Tags: java, ant, reverse-engineering, sequence-diagram

I am trying to find the execution flow in a large java code base which is not written by me. I have searched for tools which make that possible (JSonde, JTrace, Java Call Tracert, JavacallTracer), but the problem is that they all should be used with a single java/jar/class file.
The code I am trying to understand is built with Ant and has hundreds of jars. So, it runs using a shell script. I do not know how to use those tools with this code.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: A large code base can have billions of different paths.  What do you hope to learn from such a tool?  There is no magic bullet for understanding code.  You have to read it and if necessary trace it in an IDE debugger like Eclipse.

Comment: Find "the execution flow" will hardly be possible. What is the actual task you are trying to accomplish? Eclipse has most tools you need built in. Do you need a graphical representation? If yes, what should exactly be visualized?

Comment: You say (answering Mark O'Conner), "what I wanna do is make some changes in the code".  Under what conditions? How do you want to make changes [everybody wants to change code, why is your need special]? Manually? Automatically?  And what specifically do you want from "control flow" that would make that possible? (You suggest sequence diagrams. Is that what you really want? Is that the only thing you want?)

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is an old question, but now I found a solution and I put it here if somebody else searches the same thing: http://findtheflow.io/#gettingstarted.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you should consider is a code coverage tool. This will report what parts of your code are executed and which are not. There are several such tools to consider. [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) is an emerging favourite and is associated with the [Emma Eclipse](http://www.eclemma.org/) plugin.

The thing to remember about code coverage is that it needs to be driven by something. Normally this is accomplished by running your code's tests (unit or integration).

Finally, once you've comfortable with how to enable code coverage you could also consider uploading and archiving it's results in [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/).

Comment: what I wanna do is to make some changes in the code. I have already read the code several times, but that was not sufficient. The code can be imported to Eclipse,but can not be executed within Eclipse(It was built originally with command line). I generated UML class diagram out of the code. Sequence diagrams would be more useful to understand the flow, though.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want. Even if you had a tool that enabled tracing of your code (for example by enabling Java's instrumentation API) you still need something to drive your code. The most obvious mechanism is an automated test suite. As Jim Garrison pointed out there is lots of possible execution paths thru you code. (Which one is followed depends on how the program is executed). Finally in practice Code coverage reporting is a more standard form of execution analysis

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: Dynamic analysis doesn't get him control flow data.  It gets him executed code, and perhaps a branch in the call tree.  He's asking for a static analysis.

Comment: @IraBaxter I understand what he's looking for and I'm not aware of a tool that fufils the requirement. Do you? I was attempting to provide options.

Comment: Until he's clear about what his problem really is, no.  If it is really about control flow, then yes, I might know of alternatives.  Before I jump the gun, I'd prefer he was clearer about his needs.

Comment: Since I have to make changes to the code at the end, it is important to know the exact control flow to make sure I do not miss any parts.

Comment: "The exact control flow" is as other posters pointed out, billions (if not more) of paths.  That isn't what you want.  You may want some subset; the control flow paths through a specific point where you want to make the change (still billions probabaly)?.  Thru a point starting at some other point?  You answer still isn't precise enough.  You  need to say considerably more (half a sentence isn't enough); you probably need to give an answere.  Otherwise your vague question will only get vague answers, and nobody will be happy.